# Why won't Pydantic print the id as "_id"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pydantic

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel,Field, UUID1
from uuid import uuid1

class myown(BaseModel):
    id: UUID1 = Field(default_factory=uuid1, alias="_id")
    name: str


body = {"name": "skanda"}

data = myown(**body)

print(data.model_dump())
```

Hi everyone, I have been wanting to have my own `id` for a class, and I wanted to dump this into `MongoDB`. So when I call `data.model_dump()`, I want it to convert the `id` field to `_id`. That way when I push it to Mongo, it will take my `id` that I have created instead of the one auto-created by Mongo.

How do I do this? I have also tried using `serialization_alias` and `alias`. but they don't seem to work either.

Comment: `model_dump(by_alias=True)`

Answer (score 0):

```
from pydantic import BaseModel,Field, UUID1
from uuid import uuid1

class myown(BaseModel):
    id: UUID1 = Field(default_factory=uuid1, alias="_id")
    name: str


body = {"name": "skanda"}

data = myown(**body)

print(data.model_dump(by_alias=True))
```

This worked.Will be closing this. Thanks Klaus